# bash, issue with regular exepression

Tags: regex, bash, sed

given the following sentence: "something my #1 example!", in bash i want to replace everything before 'my' (my include) by 'test'.
I'm doing:

```
echo "something my #1 example!" | sed s/.+my/test/g
```

the expected result should be:

```
test #1 example!
```

but the actual result is:

```
something my #1 example!
```

I'm assuming it cannot find a matching expression, even though it's working here: http://regexr.com/3beg4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For GNU sed (the most likely case), you need to either use extended regular expressions (with one of the `-r` or `--regexp-extended` flags), or escape the `+` if you want to continue using basic regular expressions.

See the following transcript for details:

```
pax> echo "something my #1 example!" | sed 's/.+my/test/g'
something my #1 example!

pax> echo "something my #1 example!" | sed -r 's/.+my/test/g'
test #1 example!

pax> echo "something my #1 example!" | sed 's/.\+my/test/g'
test #1 example!
```

---

As per the `sed` info page:

> The only difference between basic and extended regular expressions is in the behavior of a few characters: `'?'`, `'+'`, parentheses, braces `'{}'`, and `'|'`.
>
> While **basic regular expressions require these to be escaped if you want them to behave as special characters,** when using extended regular expressions you must escape them if you want them *to match a literal character.*

---

If you're not using a `sed` that has that level of support, you can generally always turn `'.+'` into `'..*'` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: POSIX sed (GNU `sed --posix`) doesn't support `-r` or `\+`.  Using `.*.my` would work, or see my answer for cases where you have bash, but sed might be non-GNU.

Comment: @Peter, added note to that effect as an addendum.

Answer (score 0):

You said bash regex in your question title, then wrote something about sed.  Here's how to do it in pure bash:

```
foo="something my #1 example!";
while [[ $foo =~ (.+my)(.*) ]]; do    # loop instead of if, for /g.
    foo="test${BASH_REMATCH[2]}";
    #  If your pattern can match the replacement, then just loop over BASH_REMATCH[2]
done;
echo "$foo"
```

Bash doesn't have a replace-regex operator, so you have to simulate it by capturing `(.*)` before/after the part you want to modify.

This can be more efficient than `sed`, if you want to modify a string in a shell variable.  If you're just filtering stdin to stdout, sed saves you writing a `read` loop, and bash is much slower at processing large text streams than sed/grep.